# Is it possible to add two gestures in a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

As the title of this question said, I need to create a view where it needs to have action when one tap it or hold it. That means I have to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` and a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. I have already tried it. Somehow it redirect me to the screen where I needed to go, but it has affected it's back button. Affected by in the sense of it goes back to default text which is "Item" and it cannot perform it's assigned action.

Comment: yes you can do so.If you can share your code then we will help you out,why are you getting issues.

Comment: the gestures are different. If you are using button, you can use its (UIControlEvents) function

Comment: you can add two gesture but you need to remove first gesture before applying the second gesture on the view...and vice a versa

Comment: @BhavikKama I don't think that you need to remove one gesture before adding second one. You can add two or multiple different gestures one by one.

Comment: You should implement <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> methods such as `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` and add whatever gesture you want.

Comment: what about two same gesture with the diffrent type of selector method??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add these two gestures in one view. See the below code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:)];
    singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTapRecognizer];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didLongPress:)];
    [longPressRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    longPressRecognizer.allowableMovement = 1.0f;
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in my comment you can do so,here is some piece of code to help you out.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        [view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self 
                                             action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
        [view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

and here are are some links too for your better understanding:-
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this will help you out.